# Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this contex

Tags: html, css, validation, input, html-lists

HELP!!!!!! how can i fix this part of my image slider?
so it can pass the validation

it telling me that Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

errors from validator:
Line 186, Column 62: Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                
Contexts in which element input may be used:
Where phrasing content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
Error Line 197, Column 55: Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                
Contexts in which element input may be used:
Where phrasing content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
Error Line 208, Column 54: Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                
Contexts in which element input may be used:
Where phrasing content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
Error Line 219, Column 54: Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                
Contexts in which element input may be used:
Where phrasing content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
Error Line 230, Column 54: Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                
Contexts in which element input may be used:
Where phrasing content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
Error Line 241, Column 54: Element input not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                
Contexts in which element input may be used:
Where phrasing content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

```
<article>
        <div>
        <ul class="slides">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="\images\google-fonts.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2"  />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="\images\Step1.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="\images\Step2.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="\images\Step3.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="\images\Step4.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="\images\step5.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-dots">
              <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
              <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
              <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
              <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
              <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
              <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `input` inside of an `li` (this may change the look of the page).

```
        <li class="slide-container">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked /> 
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="\images\google-fonts.jpg" alt="image" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: thanks but the slider doesnt function when i do it :/ got anymore suggestions?this image slider is actually a must for this presentation thats why i just cant let go of it